# spring-data-elasticsearch @Field with nested documents

Tags: search, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have an index with this documents :

```
{
  "brand": "Renault",
  "brand_suggest": [
    {
      "input": "Renault",
      "weight": 10
    },
   ]
}
```

On the other side i'm trying to retrieve from my backoffice mapping with this object :

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Document(indexName = "brands", createIndex = false)
data class ESBrands(
        
        @Id
        @JsonProperty("id")
        val id: String? = null,

        @JsonProperty("brand_suggest")
        @Field(name = "brand_suggest")
        @CompletionField(preservePositionIncrements = false, preserveSeparators = false])
        val brandSuggest: List<String>? = null,
)
```

But it not working since i try to put the nested object :

```
{
      "input": "Renault",
      "weight": 10
    }
```

Into a list of string. But I need it to be a list of strings.
Is there a way to have this kind of syntax :

```
 @Field(name = "brand_suggest.input.*")
```

That is not working also

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

finaly adding a converter fixed the issue  :

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Document(indexName = "brands", createIndex = false)
data class ESBrands(
        
        @Id
        @JsonProperty("id")
        val id: String? = null,

        @JsonProperty("brand_suggest")
        @Field(name = "brand_suggest")
        @CompletionField(preservePositionIncrements = false, preserveSeparators = false])
        @ValueConverter(SuggestConverter::class)
        val brandSuggest: List<String>? = null,
)
```

Then the converter :

```
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.mapping.PropertyValueConverter

class SuggestConverter : PropertyValueConverter {

    override fun write(value: Any): Any {
        return value
    }

    override fun read(value: Any): String {
        val valueString: java.util.HashMap<*, *> = value as HashMap<*, *>
        return valueString.get("input").toString()
    }
}
```